# 'react/bridging/CallbackWrapper.h' file not found in React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-vision-camera

I am trying to setup my React Native app on iOS, but on build, I am always getting this error:

> 'react/bridging/CallbackWrapper.h' file not found

[image]

I have been investigating on my own and found a few people with the same problem:

- https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera/issues/1121
- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/34102

I have tried everything in these answers but no luck. Since it seems related to React Native Vision Camera, I also did everything stated in [their troubleshooting page](https://mrousavy.com/react-native-vision-camera/docs/guides/troubleshooting/).

Unforrunately I still get the error. I built the project both using **npx react-native run-ios** (which throws an endless error) and using XCode itself, where I could find the real error.

Can you help me? The app works perfectly in Android. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If nothing of the links I pasted in the question work, what finally worked for me was:

1. Updgrade React Native to >= 0.69.3 (my version was 0.69.0). To do that `npx react-native upgrade`.
2. Delete Pods folder and Podfile.lock from iOS folder. Run `pod install`.

And then building the project again.

Answer (score 1):

The way to fix the problem is to comment-out the line :

```
s.header_dir  = "react/bridging"
```

in

```
/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/React-bridging.podspec
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue and I am using react-native-vision-camera ver 2.16.1. I solved the issue by adding `s.dependency "ReactCommon"` into the `node_modules/react-native-vision-camera/VisionCamera.podspec` at the last line as shown below.

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  ...
  s.dependency "React-callinvoker"
  s.dependency "React"
  s.dependency "React-Core"
  s.dependency "ReactCommon"    <== Add this line
end
```

After made the changes, I execute `pod install` command then recompile the app again. Hope this will help those who using V2 of react-native-vision-camera.